# How do I export a chart in an image format from LibreOffice Calc?

Tags: printing, libreoffice

I want to print some charts from LibreOffice Calc, is there a way to do this?

Comment: I use SVG it's resclalable, colors can be modified in InkScape etc....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not completely sure I follow the question, so my answer is three-fold, and will hopefully hit the mark:

- to print a chart 'as is' in libreoffice, simply select it by clicking on it, and go 'file > print' but choose "selected cells" in the 'range and copies' section.
- it appears that you can't 'export' the chart directly as an image from calc, but you can paste it into libreoffice draw, and then save it as an image.
- or you can just fall back on taking a screen shot, and printing it from gimp, or shotwell, etc.

Comment: Libre Office 4.0 does allow exporting charts as images now, maybe you could update your answer accordingly

Comment: OPs question was very clear and you didn't answer it. Sorry, I am just justifying my downvote

Answer (score 7):

I was able to export a chart with these steps:

1. Select the chart (so it has a box with green squares around it)
2. Click File → *Export*
3. Click *Save*
4. In the *General* tab under *Range*  select *Selection*
5. Click *Export*

Comment: You are just exporting to pdf right? I at least don't have the option to save the chart as an image...

Comment: Thanks! I also had to set the resolution. This can be done using the dialog window that pops up during the saving process. It's important that the DPI has to be set first, and the size (either the width or the height) after that, because setting the DPI changes the size proportionally.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to export a chart with these steps:

1. copy the chart and paste it into Draw,
2. select the chart (so it has a box around it)
3. click File -> Export..., choose a file format (e.g., JPG)

   and here's the important part:
4. check the box marked "Selection".

   That will save just the chart you selected, not the chart plus the blank page it's sitting on.  Then hit "Save" and voila, you have exported the chart.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to archive this with minimal/no quality loss (since a screenshot is limited by screen resolution):

1. select a large paper format (eg. A3)
2. resize the chart so it just fits on a page (best on a new sheet)
3. export the entire document as pdf
4. open the pdf with Inkscape or Gimp, crop and save in the desired format

(There really should be and export chart to image function in libreoffice though...)